# TXT Record from a Wifi Direct Printer

Tags: android, printing, wifi-direct, bonjour, wifip2p

I'm trying to get TXT Records from Wifi Direct Printers nearby. So far, I can discover peers and establish a connection. But no luck with TXT Records.

I tried `Wifi Direct Service Discovery`, and I believe I did everything properly since I compared lots of codes from different resources including sample projects from Google and some open source Wifi Direct Wrappers in GitHub. But I couldn't make it work.

I've also seen some weird issues while trying to achieve that. e.g in some devices, when I start the peer discovery, Wifi Connection started to be turned off and on constantly.

Can someone explain how this actually works ? are `DnsSdServiceResponseListener` and `DnsSdTxtRecordListener` made for Android devices rather than Printers ?

I've also tried to listen the `MultiCast DNS IP Address (224.0.0.251)` with a `MulticastSocket` after establishing the connection between Android and Wifi Direct Printer, but I couldn't receive any data as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used "DnsSdServiceResponseListener" and "DnsSdTxtRecordListener" successfully in my current project. Both listeners are associated to discovering local services nearby.

To use them properly, you have to do the following:

#### Implement your listeners

```
WifiP2pManager.DnsSdServiceResponseListener dnsListener = new WifiP2pManager.DnsSdServiceResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDnsSdServiceAvailable(String instanceName, String registrationType, WifiP2pDevice device) { 
           // instanceName is service name and device is the print information
}};


WifiP2pManager.DnsSdTxtRecordListener txtListener = new WifiP2pManager.DnsSdTxtRecordListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDnsSdTxtRecordAvailable(String fullDomain, Map record, WifiP2pDevice device) {
            // here we get the service published information in the record map object
}};
```

### Add the listeners to your WiFiManager object

```
wifiP2PManagerObj.setDnsSdResponseListeners(mChannel, dnsListener, txtListener);
```

### Add service request

```
WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest serviceRequest = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest.newInstance();
wifiP2PManagerObj.addServiceRequest(mChannel,serviceRequest, actionListener);
```

### Finally, discover services

```
wifiP2PManagerObj.discoverServices(mChannel,actionListener);
```

After discover services is executed successfully, the listeners should receive the nearby services information.

Hope this helps.
Goodluck.

### Update

Wifi direct supported printers don't have any published services by default. To use them you have to connect to them via wifi direct and print normally as its a printer connected to your network. Note that those listeners are meant to capture published services (i.e will not capture anything for any device unless its publishing a service).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the question is not about "how to implement the Service Discovery". I've already implemented it. I discover Android Apps which broadcast their information. But I'm looking for a way to get this additional information from non-Android devices, in my case Wifi Direct Supported Printers.

Comment: Oh gotcha, Wifi direct printers don't have any published services by default. To use them you have to connect to them via wifi-direct and print normally as its a printer connected to your network. Note that those listeners are meant to capture published services.

Comment: Thanks. I thought we might get the TXT Records out of the printer since it's available via Bonjour. I tried listening MDNS-SD IP Address but it's not broadcasted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to run Bonjour discovery once the connection is established. You can see [NSD](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) and look for "_ipp._tcp" as the service type. By the way, 
for "I've also seen some weird issues while trying to achieve that. e.g in some devices, when I start the peer discovery, Wifi Connection started to be turned off and on constantly." if you're testing on a 7.1 device you might be seeing this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232714), for which a patch should be coming soon.

Comment: I've experienced the issue with Wifi Direct. Didn't upgrade to Beta 7.1.2 but I hope it gets resolved. It's really annoying. Regarding, NSD, I believe I've tried Bonjour Discovery after the connection is established since I'm running Wifi Direct discovery and NSD at the same time. But I will make sure it's the case. I will get back to you after confirmation.